# arpscan to get Mac Address, suppress first 2, last 3 lines

Tags: bash, awk

I currently get the result I want by using this:

`arp-scan -I eno1 -l | cut -f2-3 | tr [':lower:'] [':upper:'] | sed 1,2d | head -n -3`

Someone told me I am spawning too many processes and that it's just bad form. But didn't give me pointers on what 'good form' would be.

I can get close with `arp-scan -I eno1 -l | awk '{ print $2 $3 }'` but I still get the first two and last three lines.  Is there a way to, using less pipes achieve what I want to do?  In a perfect world, I get a list of:

`XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX          (<MANUFACTURER>)`

Where the gap between the mac address and the manufacturer is a tab.  Also, it has to return upper case for the mac address as it gets compared to a file to determine user of the device on my home network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (untested)

```
arp-scan -I eno1 -l | awk '{$0 = toupper ($0); CIRCBUF[NR%5] = $2 "\t" $3} NR > 5 {print CIRCBUF[(NR-3)%5]}'
```

EDIT: commented `awk` part

```
awk '
        {$0 = toupper ($0)              # convert each line to uppercase
         CIRCBUF[NR%5] = $2 "\t" $3     # fill circular buffer with fields 2 & 3
                                        # buffer index cycles every 5 lines
        }
NR > 5  {print CIRCBUF[(NR-3)%5]        # start printing at line 3 (6 - 3) and
                                        # stop 3 lines before end.
        }
'
```

Comment: That certainly looks like it works.  Does some weird stuff -- drops anything after comma in the manufacturer bit.  Had to remove the duplicate `|` after `-l` and before `awk`.  I would love an ELI5 of the `awk` portion if you have the patience and time.

Comment: @chow: Do the comments help sufficiently? And, comma should not modify the result. Space, if present, should, yes. An other-than-default field separator was not mentioned in the original request. Sorry for the duplicate `|`.

Comment: Definitely helps quite a bit.  I changed `{$0 = toupper ($0)` to use `$2` so it just capitalizes the mac address.  Why does the `CIRCBUF` need to cycle every 5 lines? And where is the specific denotation for stopping 3 lines before the end? `(NC-3)`? Thank you! (Just trying to educate myself!)

Comment: @chow: The buffer doesn't need to cycle; it's just to save memory. `CIRCBUF[NR]` will do as well. Yes, (NR-3) will last print four lines before end, and drop the rest. And starting at line 6 will leave out lines 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. :)  `awk` is like a language in and of itself.  Absolutely incredible.